# regex to select everything between slashes without the slashes

Tags: php, regex, zend-framework

I have the following which is part of a url `keyword/with/some/stuff/following`

I need a regex (PHP) that would give me the same result as 
`explode('/', 'keyword/with/some/stuff/following');`

In this case an array of matches like the following
`array('keyword', 'with', 'some', 'stuff', 'following')`

I've tried a few things including stuff from stackoverflow but without any luck

Comment: You need to give us details.  It doesn't help us at all to say "I've tried a few things".  Show us what you've tried, and then tell us what specifically is not working.

Comment: *"regex (PHP) that would give me the same result as explode"* - so why not just use explode?

Comment: have to go with regex. It's part of a regex route in Zend. btw, ~[^/]+~ didn't work

Comment: you want examples of stuff I tried? here's the latest one ``(([a-z0-9-]+)/?){1,}``

Comment: @HamZa that selects only the first.

Comment: @HamZa works with /g :) thnx mate!

Comment: @HamZa since you provided the correct reply first, if you want you can officially write an answer to mark it as correct if you want.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This would do it:

```
([^\/]+)
```

Working [regex example](http://regex101.com/r/bY9sZ3)

**PHP**

```
preg_match_all("/([^\/]+)/", "keyword/with/some/stuff/following", $matches);
```

$matches[1] =

```
array("keyword", "with", "some", "stuff", "following")
```

Comment: @ptheofan, yes it's a great regex tester! :)